# What happens if you release an unclean device context?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

Normally, if a program selects an object into a device context, or changes its properties, it should change them back before releasing the device context. What happens if it doesn't?

Let's say I do this:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(some_window);
SelectObject(hdc, some_font);
SetTextColor(hdc, 0x123456);
SetBkColor(hdc, 0xFEDCBA);
SetROP2(hdc, R2_XORPEN);
ReleaseDC(some_window, hdc);
```

and `some_window`'s window class does not have the `CS_OWNDC` or `CS_CLASSDC` flag. What happens?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/06/10399678.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the functions you listed, `SelectObject` is the only one that would cause a problem if the object is not de-selected (by selecting the original object). This would cause the `some_font` resource to be leaked because the DC would have been holding an open handle on it at the time it was released.

You should be doing this:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(some_window);
HGDIOBJ hOldObj = SelectObject(hdc, some_font);

// ... 

SelectObject(hdc, hOldObj);
ReleaseDC(some_window, hdc);
```

Or perhaps this:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(some_window);
int nSaved = SaveDC(hdc);
SelectObject(hdc, some_font);

// ... 

RestoreDC(nSaved);
ReleaseDC(some_window, hdc);
```

As [MSDN notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> Each of these functions returns a handle identifying a new object.
>   After an application retrieves a handle, it must call the
>   **SelectObject** function to replace the default object. However, the application should save the handle identifying the default object and
>   use this handle to replace the new object when it is no longer needed.
>   When the application finishes drawing with the new object, it must
>   restore the default object by calling the **SelectObject** function
>   and then delete the new object by calling the **DeleteObject**
>   function. Failing to delete objects causes serious performance
>   problems.

Comment: What if the font isn't ever destroyed anyway? (until the program terminates)

Comment: @immibis If the font is not destroyed with `DeleteObject`, it will effectively be a resource leak. `DeleteObject` will (probably) fail if you call it while the object is still selected into a DC. At end of program, however, this may not matter - but it's not good practice.

Comment: The right time to delete it would be when the program ends. What makes it a bad practice to let the OS delete it instead of deleting it explicitly? But that's a tangent from the original question.

Comment: @immibis Deleting explicity implies that you know what you're doing and not relying on default behaviour to tidy up after you. If your code is subsequently changed, the default behaviour may no longer be appropriate and it will not be obvious where and when the resources you allocated are no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

The failure to restore the original font object causes a handle leak. The OS will retain the handle to some_font.  If this code is executed repeatedly then another handle is leaked every time. You will see the Handles count in Task Manager building up. If this goes on for a long time there will eventually be painting failures that appear as junk.